# Save each Kafka messages in hdfs using spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hdfs, spark-streaming

I am using spark streaming to do analysis. after analysis I have to save the kafka message in hdfs. Each kafka message is a xml file. I can't use  `rdd.saveAsTextFile` because it will save whole rdd. Each element of rdd is kafka message ( xml file ). How to save each rdd element (file) in hdfs using spark.

Answer (score 2):

I would go about this a different way. Stream your transformed data *back into* Kafka, and then use the [HDFS connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html#quickstart) for Kafka Connect to stream the data to HDFS. Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka. The HDFS connector is open source and available [standalone](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/) or as part of [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/).

Doing it this way you decouple your processing from writing your data to HDFS, which makes it easier to manage, to troubleshoot, to scale.